# Searching for fields in geodatabase and adding them if they do not exist with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes

I have a list of files that need to be present in my featureclasses - myFields[].
I need to add these fields if they are not present in my FeatureClasses.

```
import arcpy

myField="Field01"
myFields = [field01, field02, field03]

env.workspace = "D:/test/data.gdb"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for f in fcs:
    fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(f)
    for field in fieldList:   
         if field.name == myField:
             arcpy.AddField_management(fc, myField, "TEXT")
```

This works when I only have one field, but I have a list of fields! How do I adapt this when I have many fields and many different formats? Do I have to write a separate function for each field, or is there a cool python way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I've run out of time to get this working but hopefully this will give you some ideas of the Python coding necessary to write your script:

```
import arcpy

myField="Field01"
myFields = [field01, field02, field03]

env.workspace = "D:/test/data.gdb"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for f in fcs:
    fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(f)
    for field not in fieldList:
        for myField in myFields:
            if field.name == myField:
                if field.type == "String":
                    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, myField, "TEXT")
                elif field.type == "SmallInteger":
                    ...
                elif ... :
                    ...
                else:
                    print "Field type of {0} is not yet handled".format(field.type)
```

You just needed to create another `for` loop inside your second one.  This is Python rather than ArcPy so I recommend using both Stack Overflow (for Python) and GIS SE (for ArcPy) when researching your questions.

If your fields are not all of type text, then field objects have a type property that you can use with `if`/`elif`/`else` statements to alter the type of field you add.

Comment: Is good for fields with just text, but what if field01 = int and Field02 = Date and Field03 = Long?

Comment: Field objects have a `type` property so you just need to use that with `if`/`elif`/`else` statements to alter the type of field you add.

Comment: Sorry. I´ve made a mistake.If I use " if field.name == myField " then I would be adding a field which has is already present. I need the opposite. If field.name != myField - but in this case I have the problem that I have to compare 2 lists.